# Pass OrderBy lambda function as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Let's say I have a model name `User` with a couple properties `Name` and `Age`. I would like to know the type of a lambda function that accepts a `User` and returns one of those properties such that lambda function could be used in the `OrderBy` method.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass {
    static void Main() {

        var users = new User[] {
            new User { Name = "David", Age = 16 },
            new User { Name = "Charlie", Age = 29 },
            new User { Name = "Alice", Age = 15 },
            new User { Name = "Deanna", Age = 27 },
        }.AsQueryable();

        Write(GetAdultsBy(users, u => u.Name));
        Write(GetAdultsBy(users, u => u.Age));
    }

    private static IQueryable<User> GetAdultsBy(IQueryable<User> users, Func<User, object> order) {
        return users
            .Where(u => u.Age > 18)
            .OrderBy(order); // FAIL in ORDER BY
    }

    private static void Write(IQueryable<User> query) {
        var names = query.Select(u => u.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", names));
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running [this code](https://glot.io/snippets/evx90fbrz2):

> /tmp/997240133/main.cs(26,14): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<User>' to`System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But explicitly ordering works just fine with `Write(users.OrderBy(u => u.Age));` as one might expect.

So what should be the type for `Func<User, object> order` parameter?

Comment: You can look at the signature of `Queryable.OrderBy` (either in the documentation or just using intellisense) in order to see what parameter it accepts, since you know it's not `Func<User, T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define `private static IQueryable<User> GetAdultsBy()` as a generic function to match how OrderBy< > is defined. Specifically:

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<User> GetAdultsBy<T>(
    IQueryable<User> source,
    Expression<Func<User, T>> order)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't understand. https://glot.io/snippets/evx90fbrz2

Comment: Edited answer. And in fact the specific exception you were getting was because you need the type of the selector to be `Expression< >` as per SLaks' answer.

Comment: I think `this` should not be there. Even removing it, I get an error on `u.Age` that says the following: `CS1061 'User' does not contain a definition for 'Age' and no extension method 'Age' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found`

Comment: You're right, the 'this' was a copy and  paste error, as was the extra template parameter. I've edited the answer, try with that version.

Comment: This is the right answer! I confirmed by creating a [new snippet](https://glot.io/snippets/evx9saful3) and it works as expected! Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note - the only reason you need to use `Expression<Func< >>` is because you've defined your function as working on `IQueryable`. But if you've only ever working on in-memory arrays, there's not much advantage in doing this - you could just use `IEnumerable`.  But if you do plan for this to work with a database at some point, then `IQueryable` is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

To work with `IQueryable`, you need to pass expression trees (`Expression<Func<...>>`).

The expression tree encodes the content of the lambda at runtime, allowing it to be translated to SQL.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't understand. https://glot.io/snippets/evx90fbrz2

Comment: I think this is the right track but what is the `...` in this case?

Comment: @styfle: The type parameters to `Func<...>` (the arguments & return type).  Look at the signature for `OrderBy()`.